# Dividing values of pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas

I want to divide column A of a pandas dataframe by column B. However, column B has some values that are zeros, and I want NaN (or something equivalent) to be returned.

How can I do this? Standard methods such as [div](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) return ZeroDivisionError

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far? Thanks. You could do `df.nominator/df.denominator.replace({ 0 : np.nan }).`

Comment: Can't reproduce this, performing division by zero should yield `inf` or `-inf` by definition which is what I observe, please post raw data, your code and the errors